# The smallest possible subset of nodes linked to every nodes (a variant of the minimum vertex cover?)

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I am actually working with non-weighted, undirected graphs.
I am looking for algorithms efficient in the research of the smallest possible subset of nodes of the initial graph that "touches" every other nodes (or contains it).
In a clique, any node would be the best solution.

In this graph : [image: example] there would be a multitude of solutions such as [1,4], [4,5], [2,6], etc.
It reminds me a lot of the minimum vertex coverage problem but I can't find anything about "node coverage". Has it a specific name ? Is this a common variant of the minimum vertex cover ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set

Comment: (use mixed integer programming)

Comment: Thank you I couldn't find the name of my problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471747/finding-minimum-indepedent-dominating-set-using-a-greedy-algorithm is a more appropriate question.